# Rspec can't run: rescue in connection_for': connection refused: localhost:7475 (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have been neglecting my rspec tests but trying to get back at it and now I can't get basic rspec to run.

```
rescue in connection_for': connection refused: localhost:7475 (Faraday::ConnectionFailed)
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:589:in `connection_for'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:994:in `request'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http_persistent.rb:25:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:39:in `call'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday_middleware-0.9.1/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:30:in `call'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday_middleware-0.9.1/lib/faraday_middleware/request/encode_json.rb:23:in `call'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/connection.rb:140:in `get'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-core-3.0.1/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_session.rb:41:in `open'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-core-3.0.1/lib/neo4j-server/cypher_session.rb:5:in `block in <module:Server>'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-core-3.0.1/lib/neo4j/session.rb:112:in `call'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-core-3.0.1/lib/neo4j/session.rb:112:in `create_session'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-core-3.0.1/lib/neo4j/session.rb:99:in `open'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-3.0.1/lib/neo4j/railtie.rb:57:in `open_neo4j_session'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-3.0.1/lib/neo4j/railtie.rb:73:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-3.0.1/lib/neo4j/railtie.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neo4j-3.0.1/lib/neo4j/railtie.rb:72:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Clam/rails_projects/lets_chill/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Clam/rails_projects/lets_chill/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/Clam/rails_projects/lets_chill/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Clam/rails_projects/lets_chill/spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/Clam/rails_projects/lets_chill/spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/Clam/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

I am using neo4j gem, figaro gem, koala gem, and faceook-omniauth gem. Those were my additions since it last worked.

If you need any areas of my project to reference, let me know, as I'm not sure where to be looking

Comment: A service that runs on port 7475 isn't running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your Neo4j test environment configured to run on port 7475, which is a good idea.

- Install: `rake neo4j:install[community-2.1.5,test]`
- Set the port: `rake neo4j:config[test,7475]`
- Start the server: `rake neo4j:start[test]`
- Stop the server: `rake neo4j:stop[test]` but you probably guessed that. ;-)

This is all outlined at https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/How-To-Test if you ever need reference in the future. Also make sure to run `bundle update neo4j`, you're two updates behind.